Cause of 'Assertion `_numOutstandingPackets == 0' failed' in Gem5
I'm writing a new memory dependence predictor for the Gem5 O3 CPU. Currently the memory dependencies it sets is somehow causing a load instruction to fail this assertion when it's packets are sent to cache:
gem5.opt: src/cpu/o3/lsq.cc:1325: virtual void gem5::o3::LSQ::SingleDataRequest::sendPacketToCache(): Assertion '_numOutstandingPackets == 0' failed.
Looking at the code for this assertion, it's not immediately obvious what it's intended to check for. Is anyone able to provide some context around why it's there and what is likely to be happening by failing it?
Thanks.
Backtrace:
--- BEGIN LIBC BACKTRACE ---
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem515print_backtraceEv+0x30)[0x55bb6114a070]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem512abortHandlerEi+0x4c)[0x55bb6117329c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3c460)[0x7bf491c3c460]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(pthread_kill+0x11b)[0x7bf491c9152b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x16)[0x7bf491c3c3b6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0xd7)[0x7bf491c2287c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2279b)[0x7bf491c2279b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x33b66)[0x7bf491c33b66]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem52o33LSQ17SingleDataRequest17sendPacketToCacheEv+0x17d)[0x55bb606e69cd]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem52o37LSQUnit4readEPNS0_3LSQ10LSQRequestEl+0xb1d)[0x55bb6070128d]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem52o33LSQ4readEPNS1_10LSQRequestEl+0x140)[0x55bb606e8a50]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem52o33LSQ11pushRequestERKNS_14RefCountingPtrINS0_7DynInstEEEbPhjmNS_5FlagsImEEPmSt10unique_ptrINS_15AtomicOpFunctorESt14default_deleteISC_EERKSt6vectorIbSaIbEE+0x9bc)[0x55bb606efc8c]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem52o37DynInst15initiateMemReadEmjNS_5FlagsImEERKSt6vectorIbSaIbEE+0x86)[0x55bb606ae256]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(+0x18ae921)[0x55bb5fdf8921]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZNK4gem510ArmISAInst10LDRW64_IMM11initiateAccEPNS_11ExecContextEPNS_5trace10InstRecordE+0x61)[0x55bb5fdf8a71]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem52o37DynInst11initiateAccEv+0x49)[0x55bb606ac029]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem52o37LSQUnit11executeLoadERKNS_14RefCountingPtrINS0_7DynInstEEE+0x5d)[0x55bb60704e9d]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem52o33LSQ11executeLoadERKNS_14RefCountingPtrINS0_7DynInstEEE+0x3b)[0x55bb606e705b]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem52o33IEW12executeInstsEv+0x826)[0x55bb606d0856]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem52o33IEW4tickEv+0x718)[0x55bb606d1c98]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem52o33CPU4tickEv+0x156)[0x55bb606948b6]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem510EventQueue10serviceOneEv+0xb7)[0x55bb61161607]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem59doSimLoopEPNS_10EventQueueE+0x78)[0x55bb6118c3e8]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem58simulateEm+0x27d)[0x55bb6118cb7d]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(+0x1127240)[0x55bb5f671240]
./build/ARM/gem5.opt(+0x10097ef)[0x55bb5f5537ef]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(+0x1c70e3)[0x7bf4927c70e3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(_PyObject_Call+0x58)[0x7bf49277b888]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5777)[0x7bf49270c747]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(+0x3ce13c)[0x7bf4929ce13c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0xc5)[0x7bf4928669f5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(+0x267120)[0x7bf492867120]
--- END LIBC BACKTRACE ---


what version are you using? The line you've indicated doesn't seem to contain any assertion checks https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/b88f814e633f879b71c636a6631f92b944017d5d/src/cpu/o3/lsq.cc#L1331

Sorry, the line was offset from my own debugging. It should be 1325, which as you can see in that file does have the assert. Edited my post.

The variable _numOutstandingPackets seems to record the number of the packets sent to cache, the program checks this variable when LSQ needs to send the request to cache, in this case, LSQ has two types of request named SingleDataRequest and SplitDataRequest.
Let have a quick look at the following code
void
LSQ::SingleDataRequest::sendPacketToCache()
{
    assert(_numOutstandingPackets == 0);
    if (lsqUnit()->trySendPacket(isLoad(), _packets.at(0)))
        _numOutstandingPackets = 1;
}
 
void
LSQ::SplitDataRequest::sendPacketToCache()
{
    /* Try to send the packets. */
    while (numReceivedPackets + _numOutstandingPackets < _packets.size() &&
            lsqUnit()->trySendPacket(isLoad(),
                _packets.at(numReceivedPackets + _numOutstandingPackets))) {
        _numOutstandingPackets++;
    }
}

It seems that SingleDataRequests only allow single OutstandingPackets, while SplitDataRequest can allow many OutstandingPackets
So all you need to do is to check:

Do the LSQ send request to cache twice using the SingleDateRequest
Whether you initialize the OutstandingPackets to zero

